# Symfony 2.5 Doctrine

Tags: php, angularjs, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

When I'm using Doctrine I have one problem. When I'm creating entities using console command there are classes with private properties and get and set methods for each propery. But If I used twig I wouldn't have problems, but I'm using angular and when I need all properties such a keys I have to use getPropertyName method for each property. I don't want to create my own model system, but go through the loop for each property it isn't good and convenient. Because I have to send to the angular entire objects . How can I do it easier?

The main problem that I want get object from DB make json_encode and send it to front-end, but instead of that I have to make a loop through every object and rewrite any property that I need into new array. I need something that isn't crazy like this)

Comment: Think then, why is doctrine generating getters & setters? You must use `$c->getName()` & `$c->setName()` instead of `$c->name` & `$c->name = 'Nick'`. In TWIG `article.name` is same as `article.getName` due to Twig does it automatically. Properties are private but methods (getters and setters) must be public.

Comment: You should put some of your code too...

Comment: Yes I understand it) But If I want to send it into angular and doctrine returns me big objects , I have to display it using angular and html, so i have a problem with accessing to objects fields in angular. Just 

$repository = $this->getDoctrine() ->getRepository('AcmeStoreBundle:Product');

$products = $repository->findAll();

returns me a lot of additional info that I don't need.

Comment: So make your own repository to filter what you "need": http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#custom-repository-classes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easier way is to serialize the object in json. You could do that with [JMSSerializerBundle](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSSerializerBundle)